# JS + Iframe - Not displayed when there is a class in the code

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to embed a widget

which contains iframe and script

In this structure:

```
<script defer="" type="text/javascript" src="XXXXXXXXXXXX"></script>
<iframe seamless="" width="100%" height="1000px" frameborder="0" class="XXXXXXXXX" src="XXXXXXXXX" ></iframe>
```

It cannot be displayed and you see an error message:

The server IP address of ******* could not be found.

But when I remove the class it works but it is not good because it is necessary.

What causes a class to prevent loading and how can it be displayed properly together with the necessary class??

What causes a class to prevent loading and how can it be displayed properly together with the necessary class??

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tell us what you seen in your browser devtools console and Network tab. It looks like one or both of your src attributes contain bogus values.